# Al utilizar RouteReuseStrategy para recargar componentes en agular me desactiva un menu span

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

En mi navbar tengo un botón con span que me abre un menú para el usuario al usar mi buscador y seleccionar algo me manda a la pantalla de su información pero mi botón menú deja de funcionar.

Utilice el RouteReuseStrategy porque tengo una barra de busqueda pero cuando queria cambiar mi seleccion cambiaba el id pero no el componente ni sus datos y con el rrs ya estaba funcionando como deberia, ahi fue cuando note que mi span menú no estaba funcionando, todo lo demás funciona menos ese menú

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.